# how to make a route with multiple destinies with google maps api in Android app

Tags: android, google-maps

I found some examples where only 2 points where used, origin and destiny. Its working.But i want to make a route with more than one destiny.

For example: origin --> destiny1 --> destiny2 --> destiny3 --> origin.

To build the 2 points route i send this url.

Some code:

```
//Building the parameters to the web service
String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;
String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;
```

I would like to know if i can add more destinies to the parameters. Something like:

```
String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+str_dest2+"&"+sensor;
```

Thanks all for the support.

Comment: I wanted to do this in one of my projects. Looks like you will have to make multiple requests and then combine it. I didn't find a better solution anywhere.

Comment: looks not so easy, do you have any example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its waypoint in the direction api that you are looking for
Look for "Using Waypoints in Routes" in this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/ which should give you more ideas.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Use this api for draw route from multiple waypoint .Easy implementation .[Api Link](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary)

This is my program

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, DirectionCallback,View.OnClickListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private Button btnRequestDirection;
private String serverKey = "Your_key";
private LatLng origin = new LatLng(22.992875, 72.598994);
private LatLng and = new LatLng(22.993783, 72.601482);
private LatLng destination = new LatLng(22.995008, -72.602211);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    btnRequestDirection = findViewById(R.id.btn_request_direction);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
  requestDirection();

}
public void requestDirection() {

    GoogleDirection.withServerKey(serverKey)
            .from(origin)
            .to(destination)
            .transportMode(TransportMode.DRIVING)
            .execute(this);
    Log.e("pass","1");
}

@Override
public void onDirectionSuccess(Direction direction, String rawBody) {

    if (direction.isOK()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Direction success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Route route = direction.getRouteList().get(0);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(origin));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(destination));

        ArrayList<LatLng> directionPositionList = route.getLegList().get(0).getDirectionPoint();
        mMap.addPolyline(DirectionConverter.createPolyline(this, directionPositionList, 5, Color.RED));
        setCameraWithCoordinationBounds(route);

        btnRequestDirection.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {

        Toast.makeText(this,direction.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("error",""+direction.getErrorMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void onDirectionFailure(Throwable t) {

}

private void setCameraWithCoordinationBounds(Route route) {
    LatLng southwest = route.getBound().getSouthwestCoordination().getCoordination();
    LatLng northeast = route.getBound().getNortheastCoordination().getCoordination();
    LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds(southwest, northeast);
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 100));
}

@Override
public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int id = view.getId();
    if (id == R.id.btn_request_direction) {
        requestDirection();
        Log.e("pass","1");
}
```

}}

This api have `.and(LatLong)` method which is used for waypoint use this api .